# Redactor (or Twig?) Issue stripping <R> and <TM> strings

Tags: templating, redactor

This is a Craft 3.7.x install with Redactor.

My client is writing content referencing the proper usage of their trademarks. They'd like their content to state that it's permissible to use "BRANDNAME `<R>` products" or "TRADEMARKED `<TM>` products" in lieu of a proper ® or ™ symbol if needed. However, when typing these instructions into their redactor field, the `<R>` or `<TM>` is stripped from the output, even though the content (as shown in the code block below) is retained in the backend. While they've learned they can bypass it by inserting a space between the "<" and the "R", they can overcome the issue, it's not the desired behavior. In the control panel, the field content displays as such:

```
BRAND &lt; R &gt; Products // using spaces, this will display
BRAND &lt;R&gt; Products // this will get stripped at output
```

I'm not sure whether the issue is with Redactor or Twig cleaning the text. I've disabled ALL cleaning/purifying of the Redactor field and am displaying the content with `{{entry.body|raw}}`

Can someone please point me to the setting or filter that I am overlooking here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Neither `<R>` or `<TM>` are valid html elements so I'm not surprised that they are removed, Redactor is a rich text editor it expects html.

You could either replace the Redactor field with a plain text field if you want the output exactly as typed, or your client could simply use the correct html characters `&reg;` and `&trade;`.